# Passing strings from GridView to TextBox it encodes text to &#39 and &#160

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, webforms

When I pass text value from GridView To TextBox instead of single qoute shows a code &#39 and &#160!!

Here is some of the codes:

First get text from TextBox1

```
string StringFt = TextBox1.Text;
```

than I databind it to Gridview1:

```
GridView1.DataSource = StringFt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

than send this text from Gridview1 to TextBox2(here could occur the problem somehow Gridview sends encoded strings):

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

            {
TextBox2.Text += GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
}
```

This is the mark up of GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width ="500px" Height="210px">
<Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="h1" HeaderText="h1" />
                        <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="h2" HeaderText="h2" />

 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

I tried HtmlEncode but it doesn`t change the text back to normal form...

Please note that I do not need any replace method I only want to decode or transform this &#39 and  &#160 back to normal text. I do not understand why strings are encoded when passed from GridView to TextBox, I would like to use some server side method like HtmlEncode....

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode should solve your issue

Comment: Can I ask why GridView or Textbox automatically encodes text?

Comment: It was done for browser compatibility. Some browsers would not render cells in a grid without a space - the table borders would mess up, and thus not display correctly. So, it puts in a &nbsp;, and same goes for single quotes.  This issue was I believe fixed by browser vendors, but the feature remains. Apparently you can add to the bound field a HtmlEncode="false" and it should work, or HtmlEncodeFormatString="false", but I not had luck, so, using Httputility.HtmlDecode. If you use a tempalted column with textbox, then issue does not exist, or use listview.